# Save Xlib window to eps file

Tags: x11, xlib

Is it possible to capture a xlib window and save it to an eps file?

Answer (score 1):

Use any screenshot mechanism (GNOME has a hotkey built-in to launch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-screenshot for example but there are ton of ways) to get a PNG or other bitmap file.

Then just use "convert" on the command line or an app such as GIMP to convert to eps. 
From the command line:

```
 convert screenshot.png screenshot.eps
```